nbconvert not working in VSCode and jupyter notebook
I want to convert one of my .ipynb (jupyter notebook) files to markdown(.md) for my github.

I try the code jupyter nbconvert --to markdown 'name_of_project.ipynb'
And use vscode extension jupyter to markdown
In jupyter notebook, File > Save and Export notebook AS > MarkDown

But in all of ways, i face the this error.

Python and Jupyter exist in my Environment-Path

and when type command in virtual-env, face this :
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern "'Blood_Cell_Cancer.ipynb'" matched no files
This application is used to convert notebook files (*.ipynb)

Error Image

I try the code jupyter nbconvert --to markdown 'name_of_project.ipynb'
And use vscode extension jupyter to markdown
In jupyter notebook, File > Save and Export notebook AS > MarkDown


Python and Jupyter exist in my Environment-Path

